# Response binary data to download

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to input a file from an input field, save it temporarily to the disk and reply with a response to re-download the same file.

In order to do this, I've read that I need to reply to the browser with a `content-type : application/octet-stream` and a `content-disposition: attachment; "filename=myfile.extension"`.

I can store and listen to my music file in the /tmp folder so I know that the input part of it works.

This is my code in Pyramid:

```
@view_config(route_name='process')
def process_file(request):
    input_file = request.POST['file'].file
    input_file.seek(0)
    file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', '%s.mp3' % uuid.uuid4())
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
    print(f"Wrote: {file_path}")
    filename = file_path.split('/')[-1]
    print(filename)
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    return Response(body_file=f, charset='UTF-8', content_type='application/octet-stream', content_disposition=f'attachment; "filename={filename}"')
```

These are my response headers:
[image: Response headers]

And this is my response body:
[image: Response body]

However Chrome/Firefox do not start the download of my binary file. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I also tried with `FileResponse` from Pyramid without success, I still do not get the download popup.

```
@view_config(route_name='process')
def process_file(request):
    input_file = request.POST['file'].file
    input_file.seek(0)
    file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', '%s.mp3' % uuid.uuid4())
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
    print(f"Wrote: {file_path}")
    return FileResponse(file_path, request=request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was thinking how to perform this in the wrong way. I need to return a `Response('OK')` when I upload the file through `/process` and make another request to return a `FileResponse` object, building another endpoint `/download` and returning that fileresponse object fixed this issue.

Example:

```
@view_config(route_name='process')
def process_file(request):
    input_file = request.POST['file'].file
    db = request.POST['volume']
    input_file.seek(0)
    filename = '%s.mp3' % uuid.uuid4()
    file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', filename)
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
    if boost_track(file_path, filename, db):
        return Response(json_body={'filename': filename})

@view_config(route_name='download')
def download_file(request):
    filename = request.GET['filename']
    file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', filename)
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    return Response(body_file=f, charset='UTF-8', content_type='application/download', content_disposition=f'attachment; filename="{filename}"')
```